# Reset to a previous point in time

Tags: git, visual-studio, azure-devops

I need to go back in time and assume a old version of my master branch as the right one. However when I do a hard reset all the intermediate commits appears to me:
[Branches](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VYiUx.png)
I want to go back to the surrounded red square. I do that succesfuly but when I synchronize all intermediate commits appear. What should I do?

[Incoming Commits](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j9xuX.png)

Comment: It worked following the steps:
 - Force Push permission to the user in Azure.
 - Creating a new local branch
 - Make this new branch my default one.
 - Delete remote branch.
- Push the new branch to Azure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `reset` stage is working on your loacl branch not the remote branch. So when you do a hard reset, your local branch is behind your remote branch, and the Visual Studio will automaticlly catch the behind commit between your local branch and your remote branch.

According to your expected, there are two ways you can try. The first is, reset the specific commit. Delete the branch from remote.

[image]

Then push your local branch to remote.

[image]

The second way is, choose the specific commit and create a new branch.
[image]

This new branch will have be the old version of your master branch. And if you want, you can make it as your new master branch or test branch.

Comment: Thank you @Frank Wang-MSFT. It almost worked but I'm getting an error when trying to delete my remote master branch:

Error encountered while deleting branch from the remote repository: PushCommand.ExecutePushCommand

I've created a new branch from the point I would like to revert into, but I can not delete the remote branch. Do you know why?

Comment: @FelipeCabralJerônimo, if you want to delete remote branch. You need the Force Push permission to achive the action.https://i.stack.imgur.com/b6FuJ.png

Answer (score 0):

The safe way to do this is to not `reset`, but `revert`. `Revert` will create "undo" commits. This will not be disruptive to other people who have pulled your changes.

If you **do** want to `reset`, you need to force push. Please understand the implications of force pushing before you do so, because force push has the potential to be disruptive or destructive to others.